# C# SQL query returns nothing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to get my Winforms app to query a SQL Server CE database and return all rows that correspond to the column name specified by the user through a drop down list. When I run the programs it will return just a blank dataGrid. This is my first time working with SQL Server CE so any help would be appreciated.

My code is:

```
private void srchBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.CurricularChangeTrackerConnectionString;

   using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
   {
       string queryString = ("SELECT * FROM SecondaryEducation WHERE ProgramCode='" + PrgmCde.SelectedValue + "'");

       try
       {
          conn.Open();

          using (SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(queryString, conn))
          {
              DataTable table = new DataTable();
              adapter.Fill(table);

              dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
              adapter.Dispose();
          }

          conn.Close();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you get your query that's in `queryString` (for example by setting a breakpoint in your debugger) and then run that query directly against the database using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Can you break point on this line                     dataGridView1.DataSource = table; and ensure the table is populated with something?

Comment: When you say "blank" datagrid, does it have columns at least? If so then your query is returning fine but you have no data to match your criteria!

Comment: Do you know that the way you are constructing your query has a high risk of SQL injection?

Comment: I put the break on the line dataGridView1 when looking at the table it shows all the columns but nothing beneath the column headers. As far as SQL injection what is causing it to be a high risk the user can only query based of a dropdown list that can't be edited? As I said I have never worked with SQL before so any information is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have set the **AutoGenerateColumns** property of the DataGridView to True? (It's the default, but this could be your problem)

Comment: This may seem silly, but does that actually exist in the db? Have you tried querying the db through VS? Can you capture the statement that you're creating and run that exact query against the db? As @Lamak mentioned, your approach is vulnerable to sql injection AND any associated, potential data type conversion issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a property is not specified in ValueMember, SelectedValue returns the results of the ToString method of the object.

My point is you may not be getting what you think from the comboBox.

Try this:

```
string queryString = ("SELECT * FROM SecondaryEducation WHERE ProgramCode='" + PrgmCde.Items[PrgmCde.SelectedIndex].ToString() + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the data table inside the using statement, try this

```
private void srchBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.CurricularChangeTrackerConnectionString;
   DataTable table = new DataTable();
   using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
   {
     string queryString = ("SELECT * FROM SecondaryEducation WHERE ProgramCode='" + PrgmCde.SelectedValue + "'");

   try
   {
      conn.Open();

      using (SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(queryString, conn))
      {

          adapter.Fill(table);
          dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
          adapter.Dispose();
      }

      conn.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
  }
}
```

That way the table wont be disposed of when the scope of the using statement is ended.